# How to mock functions for testing using the React Testing Library + Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm testing react components with jest/react-testing-library, and no matter what I try I am unable to mock functions correctly in my tests. Whenever I run a fireEvent that calls one of the component's functions I'm trying to mock, it calls the original function rather than the function I'm trying to mock. I've looked through all relevant questions on StackOverflow, but none of the solutions are working for me.

I've tried using both jest.fn() and jest.spyOn() and neither has worked.

My mock (for a function from component 'PasswordResetConfirmation') is as follows:

```
PasswordResetConfirmation.handleOkay = jest.fn(() => true)

test('handleOkay method is called when user clicks Okay button', () => {
  const {getByTestId} = render(<MemoryRouter><PasswordResetConfirmation/> </MemoryRouter>)

  let button = getByTestId('reset-confirm-button')
  expect(button).toBeInTheDocument();

  fireEvent.click(button) // this is where the mocked handleOkay method should be called but isn't
})
```

I would greatly appreciate any advice about how to get this function mock working.

As a follow-up, I am also trying to mock a function from a different file (not from the component I'm currently testing) in these tests and I'm having similar issues with the original function being called instead of the mock.

Thank you!

Comment: not familiar with some of the stuff you are using but can you try button.simulate('click') instead?

Comment: @TalmacelMarianSilviu that works with enzyme but not testing library

Comment: According to the devs of the library, it is intentionally done in a way that mocking component methods is hard https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/faq.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe the code below might be useful for you too.

```js
    const mockFn = jest.fn(() => true);
    const { getByTestId } = render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <RandomMeals/>
        </Provider>
        );
    const button = getByTestId("random-meals-button-test");
    fireEvent.click(button);
    expect(mockFn()).toBe(true);
```

Comment: This doesn't test anything to do with the button click as `mockFn` is never used in the React components.

Answer (score -4):

Try it with `enzyme` and `enzyme-react-adapter-15` (you have to install both thru `npm`)

Then test it like this (and note that your handleOk() can't be an arrow function):

```
import Enzyme, { mount} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
 
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });


it('...', (done) => {
    const mockHandleOk = jest.spyOn(PasswordResetConfirmation.prototype, 'handleOk').mockImplementationOnce(() => {});

    const wrapper = mount(
        <MemoryRouter>
            <PasswordResetConfirmation/>
        </MemoryRouter>
    );

    const button = wrapper.find('#reset-confirm-button');
    expect(button).toHaveLength(1);

    button.simulate('click');

    setTimeout(function() {
        expect(mockHandleOk).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: This answer over complicates things. Not only you suggest them to switch the library but and you suggest the wrong adapter from the one in your example but also you don’t really explain what your test is doing exactly. Like what’s up with the timeout

Comment: Yes, you're right... timeout is to wait for async function if there is one